# Не создаются колонки в бутстрапе

Tags: html, bootstrap

В чём моия ошибка?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <header>

    </header>
    <div class="container service">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">1</div>
            <div class="col-md-3">2</div>
            <div class="col-md-3">3</div>
            <div class="col-md-3">4</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">1</div>
            <div class="col-md-3">2</div>
            <div class="col-md-3">3</div>
            <div class="col-md-3">4</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: создаются, только необходимо прописать <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">1</div>

Comment: Работает ваш код

Comment: @soledar10, и, простите, зачем?

Comment: @Александр Белинский При разрешении меньше 992px - блоки размещались в одну колонку. (так как не задан класс .col-sm-). Поэтому необходимо задать класс .col-sm-3 (для примера)